# How to input a value in a field that has no elementID in internet explorer using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, automation

Current Code:

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "example.website"
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    Set doc = IE.document
    
    'IE.document.getElementById("userName").Value = ""
    doc.getElementById("employer-selection-code").Value = "8209"
    doc.getElementById("???")
```

I am using internet explorer 8. How can I input data into this field in IE8 without an ID to refer to.
The inspect element field is:

```
<input name="ep-input2" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-ntouched ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-required" aria-hidden="false" aria-invalid="false" type="text" etc.
```

Comment: A serious recommendation: use another solution, but no longer IE. IE11 is being actively excluded from websites right now. IE8, on the other hand, has been dead for a long time, it has already decomposed. I just want to make it really clear. Use Seleniumbasic to control another browser from VBA. I think this isn't being developed any further, but it still works with VBA and the current browsers with the associated web drivers: https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/ You will find a lot of Q&A here on SO to Selenium.

Comment: Under IE8 you can also work with `getElementsByTagName()`. This method already worked in IE6. But you already fail with `getElementsByClassName()`. This was only implemented in IE9. I can't tell you how it looks with the querySelectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Comment: querySelector will be IE9+. There is emulation mode. You will have access to .all and test. Have you verified process cannot be achieved with xmlhttp?